# Can i disable error prompts on build for locked dll files (in other workspaces) in vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there a way to disable the warning prompt that pops up when vs2010 finds a dll file locked by another user during a build? I'm using visual studio 2010 with TFS 2008.
[image]

Comment: Why are you using locks on checkouts? TFS supports shared checkouts.

Comment: I'm not the one locking them :) VS checks them out and locks them on every build. If i can tell VS to check them out and leave the locks unchanged, that will also do.

Comment: You can change the tfs setting in your workspaces to stop it doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TFS disables shared check-outs for binary files - this is enforced for any user, including the build process.

If you wish to enabled shared check-outs for all files, you can update the file extension list for mergeable files: see the [Managing File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181457.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have enough rights for that. I'll ask my administrator to give it a shot asap. Is it risky allowing merges on dll files?

Comment: Despite the name, this shouldn't actually cause any merges to occur.  The automerge engine will refuse to automerge binary files (based on examination, not file extension), so it should really only affect locks.

Comment: Thank you. This should save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try Edward's solution once i have proper rights on the TFS but for now I've changed my settings as follows:

[image]

This way it avoids the prompt, and also checks out any files i edit once i save em.